# What does こう in 何ていうかこう mean

Tags: translation

What is that こう in

> 何ていうかこう…

This is said by a character after being complimented. Apart from こう it's

> what do I say

or

> I don't know what to say

basically the character is at a loss for words. But I have no idea why does he append that こう at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 「何{なん}ていうか**こう**・・」

This 「こう」 is probably one of the most-often used "words" that are not found in the dictionary.

It is an interjection or a "filler" used when failing to find quickly the right words to describe something.  The closest English counterparts that I could think of would be "***well***" or "***you know***" used as an interjection.

> "Well, you know, how should I put it...?"

or

> "How should I put it?  It's like, umm..."

Comment: 一応、[jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%96%AF%E3%81%86)にも[デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/71492/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%93%E3%81%86/)にも[大辞林](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%96%AF%E3%81%86)にも明鏡にも載ってました。