# Meaning of とか and こう in context なんかお店とかに、こう歩ってて

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

> なんかお店とかに、こう歩ってて、なんかっす、こう、スベッ、スベッて転んだことが。痛い！

What is the meaning of こう how it’s used in this context? And what is the purpose of とか？I know なんか is similar to “like” and っす is short for です so it seems like this is a pretty informal sentence.

Answer (score 2):

[こう](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%96%AF%E3%81%86-493779) just means "like this", from このように. He might literally be demonstrating the way he was walking and how he fell as he speaks, but it's more likely that he simply used it as a filler word (in English you might use "like" in this way). As such, I believe it's used here in a similar sense as the "like" in "I was like walking, and then like, I fell, and it like hurt *so* bad!" (liberal partial translation).

[とか](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B-582055) means "and such" ([here](https://www22.atwiki.jp/2shiki/pages/203.html) are examples of usage along with some analysis), but here it again may be used simply as a filler word (in English, "n-stuff" might be a relatively close alternative). You could thus attempt to translate it as "So I was walking to the store n'stuff, and then like..." but it's not quite this obnoxious in Japanese, so the translation would not be completely faithful to the nuance.

I would add that the なんか is also just filler and could similarly be translated as "like" or maybe something to the effect of the "I dunno, like" in "I, like, I dunno, like, fell, and (...).".

And as noticed by Chocolate, the っす after なんか is likely a mistranscription, and it more likely refers to the ス in "スベッて転んだ" as the person interrupts his stuttering for a moment by interjecting こう. This would ultimately make the translation of that part go like "I, like, I dunno, f-, like, fe-, fell, and it really *hurt*!" Something similar may have occurred with the 歩ってて (presumably 歩いてて), although apparently this is also used in some [dialect](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1115659796), so it's hard to say whether this was intentional or not.

Related: [What does こう in 何ていうかこう mean](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57331/what-does-%E3%81%93%E3%81%86-in-%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%86-mean)

Comment: interesting how all these different fillers can be combined. and it was a street interview and she was just standing there while speaking, not demonstrating anything so こう must’ve just been a filler. is it commonly used as a filler? and does it have a different nuance than なんか？i speak like this in english, using “like” and other fillers a LOT, so i’d like to mimic this in japanese. なんかっす is common too?

Comment: 「なんかっす」なんて聞いたことないですねぇ。。「なんかお店とかに、こう、歩**い**てて、なんか、 **ス、** こう、 **スベッ、スベッて**転んだ...」って言ったんじゃないですかね。。。(歩ってて→歩**い**てて or **走**ってて ?)

Comment: hmm, well i copied from the subtitles written in a video so i asked based on that

Comment: @Chocolate おお……流石です。これは盲点でした