# Can't understand 'その辺うまくこう利用できるような

Tags: grammar, words

In this video clip: https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkxvmz1x_zYQepLxH7I0uV_CPevy6VgL6ya ,
the man says:

> その辺うまくこう利用できるような

I guess こう利用できるような  means 'like this, to make it usable'. But what is その辺? Is it 'this extent' or 'like that' or 'by that much(devising a method to make the time table not changing in case of snow)'? And what is うまく? I'm sorry I didn't review the Japanese grammar fully yet. I'm re-reading a book I studied during my university years (more than 30 years ago..).

I will be grateful if someone explains them with words break-down and simple grammar usage if they were conjugated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The literal meaning of その辺 is "around there", and it can be used also like "(in) cases like that", "(in) such situation" or "(regarding) that point". It's used as both an adverb and a noun. In his interview, その辺 vaguely refers to the mentioned situation/time; he is wondering if he can make use of his time in a train.
- This こう is working as a filler. It's somewhere between "well", "er" and "you know". See: [What does こう in 何ていうかこう mean](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57331/5010)

Comment: Thank you.  What about うまくこう ?

Comment: @ChanKim うまく is just 上手に/nicely/neatly.